# Argument type mismatch error using the DaysBetween() function in a calculated measure

Tags: mdx, iccube, iccube-reporting

I am using icCube 5.0.1 and in the process of upgrading to 5.1.

I am attempting to use the Builder to create a Calculated Measure using the following formula: DaysBetween([LastReportingDate], Today())

[Measure].[LastReportingDate] is a measure within the cube with a Date data type.

The purpose is to create a calculated measure that provides the number of days between [Measure].[LastReportingDate] and today and use it within a report.

When I add the new calculated measure to a report table, the column cells are filled with 'error', and when I hover over a cell the error message reads: DaysBetween(): argument (0) type mismatch: expected 'date' got: 'measure'.

Manual reference: http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/DaysBetween.php

Any hints?  Many thanks!

Comment: [LastReportingDate] is a member: can you please provide us with its name and key pattern (e.g., mm-dd-yyyy or Aug 14, 2015).

Comment: It is a measure within the cube of Date data type ( does this help?).

Comment: @Bart Marc is wondering how the date keys look in your cube. In our cubes the date keys look like this 20150815 (and are integers). In your cube maybe the keys are like this "15-08-2015" or maybe "15 Aug 2015" or maybe "15 August 2015". How do the look?

Comment: @whytheq Ah, I see. The date keys look like 2015-08-14. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and experimentation, I solved the problem as follows:

- I used the following formula for the calculated variable: Today()-[LastReportingDate]
- I used the following Cell Properties entry: Format_String = '#,##0' Note that without using the the Format_String, the report displayed a date.

Thanks to all for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the memberValue property:

```
DaysBetween([LastReportingDate].MemberValue, Today())
```

(p.s. I use Pyramid not icCube so this may be way of the mark!)

Comment: MemberValue is not supported in icCube, properties are as fast

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the [LastReportingDate] is a time dimension (i.e., with the member key being an actual date (and not a string representing a date) ) you can do the following:

```
DaysBetween( [LastReportingDate].KEY, Today() )
```

In case [LastReportingDate] is a [Measures] of type Date, you can use the Value() function to get its actual date as following:

```
DaysBetween( [Measures].[LastReportingDate].Value, Today() )
```

Note: If the key is a string, please edit your question with its pattern description.

Comment: I edited the question as requested. [Measure].[LastReportingDate] is a measure within the cube and not a dimension. Is this the information you need? I use measures like this within calculated measure formulas developed in the Builder often. Sorry I am such an MDX rookie.

Comment: @Bart: I've edited the response in case [LastReportingDate] is a [Measures].

Comment: I tried using the Value() function but it didn't work out. I received this error, DaysBetween(): argument (0) type mismatch: expected@ 'date' got: 'Min/Max'. After more experiments and research I did find a solution--see my answer. Thanks for your help